# Extends Edges in iOS7 using XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, xib

In iOS 7 when I use storyboard,  for View controller i can remove top and bottom bar using Extends Edges But in XIB file I unable to find Extends Edges When search about this, I got

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Its working fine in iOS7 simulator But still I have problem in iOS6 simulator…

Also I do Interface builder - View as “iOS6 6.1 and Earlier” and iOS 6/7 Deltas y as 15 but still can’t get it.

refer the images

[image]

[image]

just I push the ViewController (xib file) using navigation Controller… can any one help me for this whats wrong in it, how may i fix this

Comment: If you could do it (according to your design), for your UINavBar do:` [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTranslucent:NO];` if it's prior to iOS7. The "new" translucent NavBar is causing issue with iOS6. That's the easiest trick I know for keeping it that way.

Comment: @Larme: It was fix top bar problem but still I have bottom bar problem

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of your new situation?